# function get setter in typescript signature

Tags: typescript

I want to create a jQuery / d3 like API where everything the code can be chained nicely.

For instance.

```
    // set the volume property
    const foo = new OHLC().volume(func)

    // get the volume property 
    const axis = new OHLC().volume()
```

How can I overload the methods so that the return type is recognised

this is my code so far:

```
export class OHLC {
    private _volume = (d: OHLCDatum) => d.volume

    volume(fn?: (d: OHLCDatum) => number) {
        if (!arguments.length) return this._volume;
        this.volume = fn;
        return this;
    }
}
```

the problem is when I assign `const axis = new OHLC().volume(func)` returns a union type instead of the `function` type as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is indeed called ["overloading"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) and it works by providing multiple (compatible) signatures for the same function. The caller then uses the signature that matches the way they are calling the function.

So first we provide the 2 signatures that you have outlined with your use cases:

```js
volume(): (d: OHLCDatum) => number;
volume(fn: (d: OHLCDatum) => number): OHLC;
```

followed by the implementation with a signature that **all** of the overloaded signatures are compatible with. i.e. a signature that captures the effect of a caller using any of the overloaded ones.

```js
volume(fn?: (d: OHLCDatum) => number): OHLC | ((d: OHLCDatum) => number) {
    if (fn == null) return this._volume;
    this._volume = fn;
    return this;
}
```

I've changed the `if (!arguments.length)` to `if (fn == null)` which typescript is better at narrowing for the `this._volume = fn` assignment.

[Playground code example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gEgGQMIBECGwCuBbKBeKAbwDcB7AGxwgC4oA7HAIwgCcBfAbgCguIAPMKRbAoAY3JoAzpNiIkRLlCVQwLAJbEM0APplK2aAQAUAE1rxk6LNgCU+AHxQTAOj1UeyqG4NGbtU+ZyVjh2eI4M2Mws3J7eEEYAZnT+ZrKWGCEO9EysfmlIMcpxiXQA-CmB6dah4TkseRbyAD5QRgH5wbZZEVF2hIqeymoJrUn4BAzk5HYsEFgsdFDAABZqks66FFSFg0ur65v6hlBJO4Oz84sra2dsXHdcoqR0kiIJmHSi+K2pjZ01TlcWwM3C4AHowVBJHM9tA4ioWKRIMIQI9nq8TqRSJV5BMIAB3fK+IFHRIfUQ2HgQqAAcxhKzhwOgqiRrFAUDRLxEaD4awqHQyXTC2UirG+dAJRJsJKoviAA)

To support multiple properties of this format we can wrap the logic up into a function with an associate interface that uses the same overloaded signature.

```js
interface FluentProperty<C, V> {
    (): V;
    (val: V): C;
    (val?: V): C | V;
}
```

Then create the helper for making new properties. This is lacking some type safety during creation because `keyof OHLC` will not contain any private properties but class is just as type safe as before.

```
function mkOHLCProperty<V>(key: string): FluentProperty<OHLC, V> {
    return function property(this: OHLC, val?: V): OHLC | V {
        if (val == null) return (this as any)[key];
        (this as any)[key] = val;
        return this;
    } as FluentProperty<OHLC, V>
}
```

Lastly create the private field and associated property:

```js
class OHLC {
    private _volume = (d: OHLCDatum) => d.volume
    volume = mkOHLCProperty<OHLC['_volume']>('_volume')
}
```

[Playground code example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gEgGQMIBECGwCuBbKBeKAbwDcB7AGxwgC4oA7HAIwgCcBfAbgCguBLO4KwBmaAMbQAYpQgCACi1KQWoADxIANFABqAPiJcohqAAoAlLS3cjJ4mnIXzUJFaPHb5APwPaSKAB9tbjYeIUw6UWBeUjoobABreGR5RVZVXWM4iBBaAGdgFn4Ac0cpTBlgZKVVRI1tPUIDIxYILBYY0PDI6KgwBSqQY2AAC14c2hrNdy9tRxr-bX1ra14hGzt8AgZyclMoZtaYwZGcqDQTtDoQUwBtTJAAXRclk2HR0-PLm7v7-Ch3J6W+0wbSgrxyALY7ygpXKlVSIBUEzqXGCXFE5DOJzmDWsvV4tkEUAA+mRKNhoARjAATcaIVAYHC7PB6KkAOlJVEahg55N+8RqcOUCJq1wA5CSKFRRfcdMZxTyIKLTCieKJonkoB1RL9qbTkOgsNgmSz2ZLydwuAB6S1QHItUFDaAKnp9eFo9XATWkUh63ybCAAd1gdLMprJEGMWuVVpthXtwydZugvRSQqg7roGrQAA9RrRdcH9Qyjfg9AxsMwWL86IHC0hQwqzEA)

Comment: thanks good answer. I was hoping it wouldn't be so verbose. Especially since my class has 5 or 6 of these getter / setters.

Comment: No problem, I've wrapped up the volume example into a generic function/inferface to make it easy to reuse for your other properties.